# php :how i can get the unknown id of an username and password in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

hi everyone i create a  login from and it working perfectly so at the same time i'm  trying to get the  ID of the username and  password that i entered 
can anyone tell me how i can do that. Note: i'm not that kinda good in php . thank you

```
<?php
   include("login.php");
   session_start();
   $notexist="";


   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 


      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
     $id;



      $sql = "SELECT ID FROM newdata WHERE  names = '$myusername' and password= '$mypassword' ";

      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {

        $notexist="";
        echo "yes";

        echo $myusername;
       $url = "test.php?username=".$myusername;


       $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
       exit();
      }else {
         $notexist="wrong username and password";
         echo  $notexist;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Is `lastnames` your password column? It is unclear what behavior you get with this code currently. Please update the question with that information.

Comment: Note: passwords should not be stored as plain text. Hash them with `password_hash`, and verify that with `password_verify`.

Comment: `echo $row['ID'];` maybe???

Comment: AbraCadaver yes $row['ID'] it worked but how and i tried to get the name or username  echo $row['names']; but it didn't work it worked only with the id could you please explain ?

Comment: Between the `select` and `from` is a CSV of columns you are selecting. With your current query you only select the `ID`. It doesn't really make sense to return the username though, since `names = '$myusername'` means `$myusername` is the `names` value.

Comment: so if i select something else beside the id like names i can sat $row['name'] right ?

Comment: Correct, the column name corresponds to the index in the PHP because you used the `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, if you use numeric, other neither you can access by the order number, or the name. This is more clearly readable in the manual

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit:  Sorry one of my first times answering a question on here.  I will include an explanation of what is happening in all future answers.

basically when you use the mysqli_fetch_array() function you are returning two arrays for the first row of the query. One associative array, key=field name + value = return value.  One numbered array starting from index 0.  You specified to only have the associative array by using the 2nd optional parameter.

So to access the first field of the query in this can you can use $row['ID'] or $row[0].  I prefer to use the associative array as it makes the code easier to read.

You can't use this to access the fields names or password as they are not in the SELECT clause of your query.  If you wanted to access them you could use the following

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, names, password FROM newdata WHERE  names = '$myusername' and password= '$mypassword' ";
```

If you return multiple rows of data you can access each row by wrapping your fetch_array inside of a while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  //do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: yes correct but how ??? and why this method only work with id not names or other ??

Comment: appreciate the constructive feedback, have posted a more detailed explanation